# compare keys of two objects and construct a third one with same keys to reflect the difference

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare two objects and construct a third one if the value stored in a property of one is different than the other. If not I am storing an empty string. The way  am doing it in my opinion is super inefficient and non sustainable. This wont work if the keys change or their number increases. I have to be able to do this programmatically with pure JS, no jQuery:

```
var staleProfile = {
  firstName: 'john',
  lastName: 'smith',
  email: 'js@gmail.com'
}

var CurrentCustomer = {};

CurrentCustomer.profile = {
  firstName: 'paul',
  lastName: 'smith',
  email: 'js@yahoo.com'
}

var returnObj = {};

returnObj.firstName = staleProfile.firstName != CurrentCustomer.profile.firstName ? CurrentCustomer.profile.firstName : ''
returnObj.lastName = staleProfile.lastName != CurrentCustomer.profile.lastName ? CurrentCustomer.profile.lastName : ''
returnObj.email = staleProfile.email != CurrentCustomer.profile.email ? CurrentCustomer.profile.email : ''
```

Comment: Not an answer but an observation: what if one of the future properties you speak of could validly hold an empty string?  In that case, you won't know if it's been updated to a an empty string or is unchanged.  You may want to consider using `null` for unchanged items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This searches for all the object keys in the `CurrentCustomer.profile` and checks for differences to the `staleProfile`. It adds keys to the diff, that only exist in `object1` but not in `object0`, but doesn't take care of keys that are removed from `object0`to `object1`.

```
var staleProfile = {
    firstName: 'john',
    lastName: 'smith',
    email: 'js@gmail.com',
    key0: 'value0'
}

var CurrentCustomer = {};

CurrentCustomer.profile = {
    firstName: 'paul',
    lastName: 'smith',
    email: 'js@yahoo.com',
    key1: 'value1'
}

function createDiffObject(object0, object1) {
    var diff = {};
    Object.keys(object1).forEach(function(key) {
        if (!object0.hasOwnProperty(key) || object0[key] != object1[key]) {
            diff[key] = object1[key];
        } else {
            diff[key] = '';
        }
    });
    return diff;
}

console.log(createDiffObject(staleProfile, CurrentCustomer.profile));
// output:
/*
{ firstName: 'paul',
  lastName: '',
  email: 'js@yahoo.com',
  key1: 'value1' }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to make a small helper function to assign each property (or empty string):

```
// NOTE: staleProfile and CurrentCustomer are assumed to be in the scope above
// If this could be an issue, just pass them as parameters
function getProp(prop) {
  let staleProp = staleProfile[prop];
  let currProp = CurrentCustomer.profile[prop];
  return staleProp != currProp ? currProp : '';
}
```

And then use it like:

```
let returnObj = {
  firstName : getProp('firstName'),
  lastName  : getProp('lastName'),
  email     : getProp('email')
}
```

Running Example

```js
var staleProfile = {
  firstName: 'john',
  lastName: 'smith',
  email: 'js@gmail.com'
}

var CurrentCustomer = {};

CurrentCustomer.profile = {
  firstName: 'paul',
  lastName: 'smith',
  email: 'js@yahoo.com'
}

function getProp(prop) {
  let staleProp = staleProfile[prop];
  let currProp = CurrentCustomer.profile[prop];
  return staleProp != currProp ? currProp : '';
}

let returnObj = {
  firstName: getProp('firstName'),
  lastName: getProp('lastName'),
  email: getProp('email')
}

console.log(returnObj);
```

The advantage of this helper function is that, in case you need to update your strategy for replacement of a missing value, you only have to do it in one place.

---

Furthermore, you could have an array of keys you would like to extract:

```
let keys = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email'];
```

Or perhaps extract all using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
let keys = Object.keys(staleProfile);
```

And then you can store the keys using the `getProp` function:

```
keys.forEach(k => {
  returnObj[k] = getProp(k);
});
```

This would make adding/removing properties simply a matter of the current content the `keys` array. When you need to remove or add a property, you can either update the `keys` array in the first example, or update the `staleProfile` in the second example and let `Object.keys` return the values for you. Either way, with one small change you can add/remove properties.

Running example:

```js
var staleProfile = {
  firstName: 'john',
  lastName: 'smith',
  email: 'js@gmail.com'
}

var CurrentCustomer = {};

CurrentCustomer.profile = {
  firstName: 'paul',
  lastName: 'smith',
  email: 'js@yahoo.com'
}

function getProp(prop) {
  let staleProp = staleProfile[prop];
  let currProp = CurrentCustomer.profile[prop];
  return staleProp != currProp ? currProp : '';
}

let keys = Object.keys(staleProfile);
let returnObj = {};

keys.forEach(k => {
  returnObj[k] = getProp(k);
});

console.log(returnObj);
```

*Note*: **James Thorpe** made a good observation in the comment.

> what if one of the future properties you speak of could validly hold an empty string? In that case, you won't know if it's been updated to a an empty string or is unchanged. You may want to consider using null for unchanged items

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to get all the `keys` present in your object using `Object.keys(staleProfile)`.

After this you can loop through the keys and compare values. See an example down below.

```
var keys = Object.keys(staleProfile),
    i, j,
    comparedObject = {},
    key,
    CurrentCustomer = {
       a:a,
       b:b,
       c:c
    };

for (i = 0, j = keys.length; i < j; i++) {
    key = keys[i];

    if (staleProfile[key] === CurrentCustomer[key]) {
        comparedObject[key] === CurrentCustomer[key];
    } else {
        comparedObject[key] === '';
    }
}
```